# Only in Opera: JSON.parse: Unterminated string

Tags: ajax, json, string, parsing, opera

In Opera only I receive `"JSON.parse: Unterminated string"` when going to http://www.underfashion.nl/babys
The string is indeed unterminated, does not end with `"]}`.

In the other browsers (IE, FF, Chrome) it works fine and receives the entire string.

The string is very long: 217529 chars. Is that possibly the problem? The other browsers receive 220374 chars ending with `"]}`

I have tried 3 AJAXways to get the data, all with the same strings as result:
The first:

```
var value = (function () {
     var val = null;
    $.ajax({'async': false, 'global': false, 'url': uf_urlsearch,
         'success': function (data) { val = data;
alert("Data Loaded: " + data.slice(-100) + "<br/>Numofchars: " + data.length);
         }
     });
    return val;
 })();
```

The second:

```
$.get(uf_urlsearch, function(data){
alert("Data Loaded: " + data.slice(-100));
});
```

The third:

```
uf_XMLHttpProductlist.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (uf_XMLHttpProductlist.readyState==4 && uf_XMLHttpProductlist.status==200){
//Get the returned menu-items in Responsetext, expected to look like this:
  ...
  };//if (uf_XMLHttp.readyState==4 && uf_XMLHttp.status==200){
};//uf_XMLHttp.onreadystatechange=function()

uf_urlsearch = "http://www.underfashion.nl/php/get_productlist.php?"+uf_PHPsearchstring;
uf_XMLHttpProductlist.open("GET",uf_urlsearch,true);
uf_XMLHttpProductlist.send();
};
```

Anyone see any solution?

Best regards,

Comment: I just tested on Opera/Ubuntu and the json answer seems complete.

Comment: Dystroy, Thanks for your comment. So it narrows down to: Only in Opera/Windows. I have now also tried it with a shorter strinof 159719 chars. Same problem: the last 4000 chars or so do not get passed.

Comment: This was in Opera 11. I now upgraded to 12, but still the same problem occurs.
Also I tested various datasets and found out that with small amounts of data it does not occur, but some large dataset also parse correctly. So there is no absolute limit.

Comment: Did you look at what really pass on the network using a sniffer ? Are there no error in your server log ?

Comment: No not yet. Never sniffed yet. Any hints on how to do that in Opera? And checking my serverlogs now I see lots of errors 'PHP Notice:  Undefined index: merk in /domains/underfashion.nl/public_html/php/get_productlist.php on line 11'

Comment: But that PHP-message is minor and I now solved it using isset() before doing $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

To inspect the network activity, Go to Opera Menu -> Tools -> Advanced -> Opera Dragonfly. Then enter the URL in your addressbar.

In the Network Tab you can see the list of resources. Select the XHR button, and you will see the get_productlist.php resource. For what is worth, I didn't have any issue with your Web site. The HTTP Request was:

```
GET /php/get_productlist.php?afdeling=babys HTTP/1.1 
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7.4; U; fr) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.00
Host:   www.underfashion.nl
Accept-Language:    fr,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7,pt;q=0.6,de;q=0.5,zh-CN;q=0.4,es;q=0.3,it;q=0.2,nl;q=0.1,sv;q=0.1,nb;q=0.1,da;q=0.1,fi;q=0.1,zh-TW;q=0.1,ko;q=0.1,pl;q=0.1,pt-PT;q=0.1,ru;q=0.1,ar;q=0.1,cs;q=0.1,hu;q=0.1,tr;q=0.1,ca;q=0.1,el;q=0.1,he;q=0.1,hr;q=0.1,ro;q=0.1,sk;q=0.1,th;q=0.1,uk;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Referer:    http://www.underfashion.nl/babys
Cookie: JSESSIONID=9ABC3B0357487E01298EBC7A02B5FDCD; __atuvc=1%7C25; __utma=137714676.906129982.1340200451.1340200451.1340200451.1; __utmb=137714676.1.10.1340200451; __utmc=137714676; __utmz=137714676.1340200451.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmv=
Connection: Keep-Alive
X-Requested-With:   XMLHttpRequest
Accept: */*
```

Now the HTTP Response is interesting:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date:   Wed, 20 Jun 2012 13:54:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:   PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.15
Vary:   Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding:   gzip
Content-Length: 11469
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type:   text/html
```

Then the json content. Do you see what is wrong in the HTTP response above? YUP.

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

The mime type for JSON is defined in [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627). Please send with JSON content the following mime type.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

That said You are saying that you still have the issue (I don't) on some specific URIs. Could you share which one?

Comment: Hi Karlcow, Thanks! I added 'header('Content-Type: application/json');
' to my php-file and it received the entire data! 10 points for you. Unfortunately my site now runs into another error stating the he is ; "unable to parse value: object" (see underfashion.nl/heren or any other page on underfashion.nl) Tryingto figure that out now.

Comment: Yes! After setting the header the datatype changed of course and that caused that I no longer needed to do JSON.parse(data) on the receiving end. The data was passed as JSON and correctly read. THANKS GUYS!